# Token Authentication in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a beginner in the world of Rails. Can someone please explain to me like I am a 2 year old. What in the world does token authentication do? Is it recommended for your app from a security standpoint or you are fine just without it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token authentication is usually used to create auto-signin links in your emails.

User clicks on link like http://example.com/some_page?auth_token=some-very-secret-token, which contains token and is recognized by token value.

So there is no need to remember password to unsubscribe from your site emails, for example.

Comment: I see. So I dont really need it. If I dont implement it it is not going to be a security issue, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Security tokens provide the "what you have" component in 2 factor / multi-factor solutions.

As talking to a two year old,

You want to get in the house. You would need a 'key' - a token that the system can identify you with.

Comment: the key part makes sense but is it ONLY and the RECOMMENDED way to get in?

Comment: Entirely depends on what you are trying to achieve. One solution does not fit all. But if you are talking about changing password / unsubscription etc. then yes.